# Как закешировать страницу, что б при возвращении "назад" отображались не в изначальном виде, а до перехода?

Tags: javascript, кэширование

Как закешировать страницу, чтоб при возвращении "назад" отображались не в изначальном виде, а до перехода? Смысл в том, что пользователь выбирает данные по фильтру и потом меняется урл, но при если он вернётся "Назад", что б отображались не первоначальные данные, а выбранные до перехода.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно каким-то образом сохранить состояние страницы. При изменении состояния страницы вы можете менять #hash в URL, например `http://example.com/page#mode=search&search=foobar`. При возвращении назад браузер восстановит в том числе #hash. Тогда вы сможете по параметрам из #hash привести страницу в состояние, в котором она должна быть.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать как #hash, так и localStorage (или куки) для хранения состояния страницы, либо устанавливать Cache-Control (no-store, must-revalidate), если состояние страницы (выбранный фильтр) сохранился на сервере. Более подробное описание здесь:

[Как перехватить кнопку "назад" браузера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621046/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)