# Как перехватить кнопку "назад" браузера?

Tags: javascript, http, button, кэширование, браузер

На странице используется JavaScript, пользователь может изменить вид страницы. При переходе по ссылке на другую страницу того же сайта и затем нажатии на кнопку "Назад" браузера, теряются сделанные пользователем изменения на первой странице.

Как перехватить событие возврата на страницу, чтобы можно было ее обновить?

Comment: Вам нужно не перехватывать "назад", а сохранять изменения на первой странице (на бэкенд, или на клиенте, в local storage или куки), и восстанавливать его при навигации назад.

Comment: @PashaPash или в историю

Comment: @PashaPash, расскажи это разработчикам SO)))

Comment: @Qwertiy незапощенные ответы на SO сохраняет браузер, а на все остальное они забили из соображений простоты :)

Comment: Изменения на первой странице и так сохраняются (на сервере), но чтобы их восстановить - требуется перехватить событие возврата на страницу...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перехватить событие возврата на страницу не получилось, задача решена другим способом.

Я добавил на стороне сервера в http-заголовок Cache-Control значения no-store, must-revalidate, как написано здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers

Таким образом, при нажатии "Назад" страница автоматически обновляется браузером вообще без использования дополнительного кода JavaScript. Сделанные пользователем изменения при этом не теряются, т.к. они до этого были сохранены на сервере.

При обновлении страницы по F5 также получаем с сервера самое последнее состояние страницы.

Если бы состояние хранилось не на сервере, пришлось бы дописать немного JavaScript-кода (для работы с localStorage или куками), но history.replaceState я бы использовать не стал. Вместо хранения состояния (на стороне клиента) в history, гораздо удобнее хранить то же самое состояние в localStorage.

Answer (score 2):

Раз пользователь может изменить вид страницы, значит, работает javascript. В нем надо при обработке пользовательских действий подменить последний элемент в истории браузера, чтобы возврат происходил уже на указанную вами страницу (или тот же адрес, но с параметрами).

Вот [пример](http://sws-group.zephyrlab.ru/projects/).

Код скрипта:

```
$('.portfolio_filter').each(function(){
    var $this_filter = $(this);

    $this_filter.on('click', 'a', function(){
        var project_type = $(this).data('optionValue').slice(1);
        var url = window.location.href;
        if (url.indexOf('?') >= 0) {
            url = url.slice(0, window.location.href.indexOf('?'));
        }
        if (project_type) {
            url = url + '?type=' + project_type;
        }
        // console.log('url: ' + url);
        window.history.replaceState(null, document.title, url);
        return false;
    });
});
```

При клике не кнопку на странице в историю дописывается url типа `http://sws-group.zephyrlab.ru/projects/?type=commercial` После просмотра проекта категории commercial возврат идет уже на url с `?type=commercial`.

Comment: В таком случае (обработка любого перехода по ссылке) лучше все-таки использовать `replaceState`, а не `pushState`. Иначе пользователю придется нажимать кнопку "назад" два раза, чтобы покинуть эту страницу.

Comment: Согласен, спасибо за полезное замечание

Comment: @PavelMayorov поправил скрипт на сайте

Comment: В качестве примера приведен довольно глючный сайт, особенно под отладчиком он не хотел нормально работать, плюс куча минифицированного кода, в котором не разберешься. Но что интересно - нужный функционал там был. Правда, он был не в javascript, а в заголовке Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate. У меня же было просто Cache-Control: no-cache.

Answer (score 1):

В комментариях верно написали, что ответ кроется не в перехвате события "назад" у браузера, а сохранении состояния страницы

Например, пользователь может изменить тему страницы. Что бы при возвращении на эту страницу, была выбрана нужная тема, сохраним ее в `localStorage`

```
const savePageState = (name, state) => {
    localStorage[name] = state;
}

const loadPageState = (name) => {
    return localStorage[name];
}
```

Дальше, при нужных вам событиях, вы просто сохраняете в `localStorage` нужные вам данные, а при загрузке страницы (`onload` событие, например) выгружаете нужные данные и используете их

Comment: localStorage восстановит состояние даже если пользователь не нажмет "Назад" - а откроет страницу в новом окне. На следующий день. Если нужна обработка только кнопки ""Назад" - то localStorage не подойдет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не так сложно добавить проверку на время или другие условия для удаления состояния.

Comment: Но это будут только эвристики, работающие в ограниченном числе случаев. В общем случае отличить нажатие кнопки "Назад" от перехода по ссылке без использования History API невозможно.

Comment: С сохранением состояния у меня все в порядке, проблема с восстановлением, т.к. window.onload хотя и вызывается при нажатии "Назад" в IE 11.576, но не вызывается при нажатии "Назад" в FireFox 51.0.1.