# Как сделать что бы при нажатии на кнопку хрома назад открывалась страница с которой был переход на страницу с формой добавления?

Tags: php

На странице есть форма с добавлением картинки и данных .При нажатии на кнопку отправить картинка и данные добавляются , но при нажатии на кнопку хрома назад  появляется страница с заполненными в соответствии отправленным данным полями и так появляется такие поля в последовательности в которой были добавлены картинки.Как сделать что бы при нажатии на кнопку хрома назад открывалась страница с которой был переход на страницу с формой добавления и почему так не происходит ?
Работаю с денвером . 
Если сделать отдельный файл для добавления данных в базу с перенаправлением обратно в файл с формой  происходит тоже самое , но в firefox в таком случае работает как надо , но если все в одном файле то и в firefox  как надо не работает.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">

<header>

<ul>
<li><a href="cod.php?category=tea"><p>tea</p></a>
<li><a href="cod.php?category=coffee"><p>coffe</p></a>
</ul>
</header>


</div>
<div class="wrap">
<form name="form1" method="post" action=""
enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="text" name="given_name" size="12">
<p><select size="1"  name="category">
    
    <option value="tea">tea</option>
    <option  value="coffee">coffee</option>
   
   </select></p>
 <p><input type="file" name="file" />
   <input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
</div>
<?php
$host = 'localhost'; // адрес сервера 
$database = 'imagess'; // имя базы данных
$user = 'admin'; // имя пользователя
$password = '12345'; // пароль
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
    or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
 
 
$given_name=$_POST[given_name];
$category=$_POST[category];

if(substr($_FILES['file']['type'], 0, 5)=='image')
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    
 
    if (file_exists('upload/'.$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      'upload/'.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]));
      $image=('upload/'.$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
   $imageProperties = getimageSize('upload/'.($_FILES["file"]["name"]));
      }
    }
  }



 

//...
// Используя ранее определенную функцию get_image присваиваем
// переменным содержимое файлов

$name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
if ($image == ''){
 unset($image);
}
// ...
// 

if (isset($image)){
 
 
 $result = mysqli_query ($link,
  "Insert INTO imagess (img,imageType,category, name, showname) 
  VALUES ('".$image."','".$imageProperties['mime']."','".$category."','".$name."','".$given_name."') ");
  
 
 
  mysqli_error;
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Так происходит потому-что предыдущая страница и есть форма. Не понял что там в filrefox происходит. Мне кажется лучший вариант делать отправку аяксом, убивать форму и выводить результат. В таком случае страница с форой и результатом будет одной и той же страницей.

Comment: Тут посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621046/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0